# Split list into sublist ID wise C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, split

Suppose, I have a list of Journals:

```
class Journal { public int ID; public string Name; }

var objListJournals = new List<Journal>
{
    new Journal{ID = 1, Name = "Tom"}, new Journal{ID = 2, Name = "Jerry"}, 
    new Journal{ID = 1, Name = "Brad"}, new Journal{ID = 3, Name = "Frog"}, 
    new Journal{ID = 1, Name = "Alex"}, new Journal{ID = 2, Name = "Don"}
};
```

Now I want is, this list would be split according to ID wise. So it should be like that:

```
list 1: {ID=1, Name="Tom"},{ID=1, Name="Brad"}, {ID=1, Name="Alex"}
list 2: {ID=2, Name="Jerry"}, {ID=2, Name="Don"} 
list 3: {ID=3, Name="Frog"}
```

so that I can add them into a new list-

```
List<Journal> objNewList = new List<List<Journal>>();

objNewList.Add(list1);
objNewList.Add(list2);
..........
```

How to do?

Comment: I guess objNewList is List<List<Journal>>, not List<Journal>

Comment: So? What have you researched? (`GroupBy`....)

Comment: And please post code that compiles. The code where you initialize objJournalList doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your question would contain valid code:

```
class Journal { public int ID; public string Name; }

var journals = new List<Journal>
{
    new Journal{ID = 1, Name = "Tom"}, new Journal{ID = 2, Name = "Jerry"}, 
    new Journal{ID = 1, Name = "Brad"}, new Journal{ID = 3, Name = "Frog"}, 
    new Journal{ID = 1, Name = "Alex"}, new Journal{ID = 2, Name = "Don"}
};
```

That actually compiles to a list, you can use Linq to [groupby](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) to group your instances by one of their members into groups.

This will give you an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,Journal>>` which you can flatten down by using a `Select` to a `IEnumerable<List<Journal>>` - if you really need `List<List<Journal>>`, call `ToList()` on that:

```
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    class Journal { public int ID; public string Name; }

    static void T()
    {
        var journals = new List<Journal>
        {
            new Journal{ID = 1, Name = "Tom"}, new Journal{ID = 2, Name = "Jerry"}, 
            new Journal{ID = 1, Name = "Brad"}, new Journal{ID = 3, Name = "Frog"}, 
            new Journal{ID = 1, Name = "Alex"}, new Journal{ID = 2, Name = "Don"}};

        var listById = journals
            .GroupBy(j => j.ID)       // grouping into IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,Journal>>
            .Select(i => i.ToList()); // flattening to IEnumerable<List<Journal>

        foreach(var list in listById)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", 
                list.Select(l => string.Format("ID: {0} -  NAME: {1}", l.ID , l.Name))));
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        T();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ID: 1 -  NAME: Tom,ID: 1 -  NAME: Brad,ID: 1 -  NAME: Alex
ID: 2 -  NAME: Jerry,ID: 2 -  NAME: Don
ID: 3 -  NAME: Frog
```

Comment: Although its late, but Thank you for nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem without List of lists:

```
            var journals = new List<Journal>
        {
            new Journal {ID = 1, Name = "Tom"},
            new Journal {ID = 2, Name = "Jerry"},
            new Journal {ID = 1, Name = "Brad"},
            new Journal {ID = 3, Name = "Frog"},
            new Journal {ID = 1, Name = "Alex"},
            new Journal {ID = 2, Name = "Don"}
        };
        var res =
            journals.GroupBy(x => x.ID, y => y.Name)
                .Select(x => new {ID = $"ID: {x.Key}" , Names = $"NAMES: {string.Join(", ", x)}"})
                .ToList();
        foreach (var item in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID} {item.Names}");
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use `GroupBy`;

```
var result = objJournalList.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.Select(k => k));
```

Comment: The question is pretty clear and my answer is best proper way to get desired result. What is wrong ?

Comment: (not downvoter). Never claimed answer is wrong. I think it is correct. All I said is that question is posted with showing 0 effort. I am sure OP tried before posting but the question doesn't show it. Some basic googling and linq tutorial would have gave the answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It could be better that the OP shows effort on it. I would wish it too. But I think, it is not a reason to downvote a correct answer opposite to clear question.

Comment: As I said I didn't downvote... But I am sure if you look it up on meta you will find a question about it ;)